# htaccess redirect URL using partial value of string parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a bunch of products listed at

```
https://www.example.com/all/products/foldername/1234567890-ProductDescriptionA-456.html
https://www.example.com/all/products/foldername/7654321-SomeOtherDesc-B123.html
https://www.example.com/all/products/foldername/93939393-anotherthing-F93939393.html
```

and I want these to be redirected to

```
https://www.example.com/products.php?p=1234567890
https://www.example.com/products.php?p=7654321
https://www.example.com/products.php?p=93939393
```

respectively. Is there an htaccess rule to do string operations on a matched parameter? For example, if I had to convert my URL using Python, it would look like this:

```
def make_new_url(old_url):
    product_id = old_url.split('/')[-1].split('-')[0]
    new_url = 'https://www.example.com/products.php?p=%s' % product_id
    return new_url
```

In the old URLs, the product ID is found after the last "/" and just before the first "-". Another regular expression based rule that would work would be:

```
\/(\d*?)\-
```

Any thoughts as to how to accomplish this inside an Apache htaccess file?

Comment: Do you want URLs to change to `https://www.example.com/products.php?p=1234567890` in browser?

Comment: Yes. When a request is made to the server for `https://www.example.com/all/products/foldername/1234567890-ProductDescriptionA-456.html` I want `https://www.example.com/products.php?p=1234567890` to be returned. I don't care about any of the content except _SOMENUMBERS_ in: `...../foldername/SOMENUMBERS-otherstuff.html`

Comment: Hmm then either of 2 answers should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RedirectMatch ^.*\/(\d+)\-.*$ products.php?p=$1
```

The rewrite rule matches the number inside a capture group and then substitutes it for $1.

Comment: I think the OP is saying that the top three URL examples are the *old* ones. As such, those should be redirected and not rewritten.

Comment: This was good enough for me to tweak it to get it working successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RedirectMatch ^/all/products/foldername/([0-9]+)-productDiccriptionA-([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.html$ https://example.com/product.php?p=$1
```